# How to make tensorflow-serving example work

Tags: tensorflow-serving

I am trying out the tensorflow example from the tutorial [page](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/serving/docker)

at the third step

```
# Start TensorFlow Serving container and open the REST API port
docker run -t --rm -p 8501:8501 \
-v "$TESTDATA/saved_model_half_plus_two_cpu:/models/half_plus_two" \
-e MODEL_NAME=half_plus_two \
tensorflow/serving &
```

I get the following error message
2020-07-19 11:54:52.858203: E tensorflow_serving/sources/storage_path/file_system_storage_path_source.cc:362] FileSystemStoragePathSource encountered a filesystem access error: /models/half_plus_two; Permission denied

This is continuously repeated. I have installed the demo model as mentioned in the tutorial.

```
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/serving
TESTDATA="$(pwd)/serving/tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow/testdata"
```

Can someone please help what am i missing? I am just starting off on the serving part.

Thanks

Krishnan

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be with your `-v` parameter where you are binding the path.

Try (Change the `source` parameter):

```
docker run -p 8501:8501 --mount type=bind,\
source=/path/to/yourmodels/,\
target=/models/half_plus_two/1 \
-e MODEL_NAME=half_plus_two -t tensorflow/serving
```

Comment: Docker version is 1.13 running on Centos. the mount option is not there, I had checked this earlier too.

Comment: upgrading the docker version worked. Current version is Docker version 19.03.12, build 48a66213fe.